# Update date column with sysdate based on the interval

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I need to create a plsql script that must update the population_date column with sysdate based on the population interval (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly) when executed.

For example,  if it is a weekly population interval, the existing date in the population_date column must be updated as follows:

Rec_sid    (existing date)  Population_date

1                 20-jan-2020    sysdate(03-aug-2020)

2                 20-jan-2020    sysdate (03-aug-2020)

3                 19-jan-2020    sysdate-1(02-aug-2020)

4                 19-jan-2020    sysdate-1(02-aug-2020)

5                 18-jan-2020    sysdate-2(01-aug-2020)

6                 18-jan-2020    sysdate-2(01-aug-2020)

7                 17-jan-2020    sysdate-3 (31-jul-2020)

8                 17-jan-2020    sysdate-3(31-jul-2020)

9                 17-jan-2020    sysdate-3(31-jul-2020)

10               16-jan-2020    sysdate-4(30-jul-2020)

11                16-jan-2020    sysdate-4)30-jul-2020)

12                15-jan-2020    sysdate-5(29-jul-2020)

13                15-jan-2020    sysdate-5(29-jul-2020)

14                14-jan-2020    sysdate-6(28-jul-2020)

And this column exists in 100 tables with different structure and the population_date column alone must be updated with the current date based on the interval.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. How do you get `03-aug-2020` from `20-jan-2020` in line 1?

Comment: the existing date (20-Jan) in the column must be updated to the sysdate(03-Aug)

Comment: You mean sysdate? Or some calculated date? I mean why is it 03-Aug? Is that because it's August 3 today, so you just put the actual date in parenthesis? Also, what do you mean by "(hourly, daily, weekly, monthly)"?

Comment: Yeah, sysdate.. Since it was posted yesterday, for better understanding, the sysdate (03-aug) is mentioned.

Comment: Ok. You should update your Question to reflect that you just mean the date when the script runs and the the date in parenthesis is just reflecting that. I still do not understand what you mean by "(hourly, daily, weekly, monthly)". Do you mean you want a timestamp too? Not just a date? It would help if you could elaborate with examples in your Question with what the data is before your update and what the data should be after your update. Right now it seems to be a mix of before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent date on the same day of the week on or before today.  That logic would be:

```
population_date + floor( (sysdate - population_date) / 7) * 7
```

You can put this into an `update` as:

```
update t
    set population_date = population_date + floor( (sysdate - population_date) / 7) * 7;
```

I would advise you to run a `select` first to validate the results.

Comment: Thanks much! It helped.                                 How can the date be updated when it is hourly, monthly, quarterly intervals, respectively?  Could you please help?

Comment: The same basic idea can be used . . . but you might need `months_between()` to handle anything measured in months.